# Map nested object to array

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have been hitting my head against a wall all day trying to solve this problem and also having searched on here i have found nothing as of yet.

My current object that is returned from an API is structured as so, i have over 2000 data points for each device:

```
{ "DeviceA": [

     {  "device_id": "DeviceA",
        "time": "2021-01-23T18:43:14Z",
        "temperature": 1.875,
        "strength": -14.827574,
        "maturity": 105.904513
     },
     {  "device_id": "ExampleB",
        "time": "2021-01-23T18:53:14Z",
        "temperature": 1.35,
        "strength": -145.64274540827574,
        "maturity": 10.904513
     },
             ]

 "DeviceB": [
     {  "device_id": "DeviceB",
        "time": "2021-01-23T18:43:14Z",
        "temperature": 1.5,
        "strength": -120.64274540827574,
        "maturity": 3233.04513
     },
     {  "device_id": "ExampleB",
        "time": "2021-01-23T18:53:14Z",
        "temperature": 1.875,
        "strength": -17.4274540827574,
        "maturity": 10554.268851904513
     },
}
```

And how i want it

```
[
  {
    "id": "DeviceA"
    "Data": [
      {
         "x": "time"
         "y": "temperature"
      }
     ]
  }
  {
    "id": "DeviceB"
    "Data": [
      {
         "x": "time"
         "y": "temperature"
      }
     ]
  }
]
```

I have tried nesting mapped arrays, millions of things but i can never get the right output. Any help would be massively appreciated!

Edit:

Apologies i had not included some code for what i was working on

```
  const graphAllTempVTime = () => {
const sensorTempVTimeMapped = Object.entries(sensorDatasFromCast).map(
  (items, index) => ({
    id: items[0],
    data: [
      {
        x: items[1].time,
        y: items[1].temperature,
      },
    ],
  })
)

return sensorTempVTimeMapped
}
```

However this produces the output of:

[image]

Comment: Just making sure I have this right. So your API is pushing out a giant object and not an array with objects?

Comment: Yes exactly.  The top level is an object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to map over the value for each key.

```js
let o = { "DeviceA": [ { "device_id": "DeviceA", "time": "2021-01-23T18:43:14Z", "temperature": 1.875, "strength": -14.827574, "maturity": 105.904513 }, { "device_id": "ExampleB", "time": "2021-01-23T18:53:14Z", "temperature": 1.35, "strength": -145.64274540827574, "maturity": 10.904513 }, ], "DeviceB": [ { "device_id": "DeviceB", "time": "2021-01-23T18:43:14Z", "temperature": 1.5, "strength": -120.64274540827574, "maturity": 3233.04513 }, { "device_id": "ExampleB", "time": "2021-01-23T18:53:14Z", "temperature": 1.875, "strength": -17.4274540827574, "maturity": 10554.268851904513 } ] };
const res = Object.entries(o).map(
  ([key,val], index) => ({
    id: key,
    data: val.map(x=>({x:x.time, y: x.temperature}))
  })
)
console.log(res)
```

Comment: This works fantastic and is far the fastest performing answer! Thanks ever so much!!

Comment: @AndreaCorrado Happy to help.

Answer (score 2):

You could use: [Object.keys() - check the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) It will take an object (like your first example) and returns the keys as an array, from there you could traverse each key and transform each value. You could also check [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) it is newer so be aware of the platform support.

It could be helpful if you post some of the code that you are trying, and maybe the community could spot a fix

Comment: Apologies for the lack of code, i have added it now, and thanks for your advice

Comment: Don't worry. I'm seeing that there is people already trying to help you, my next advice will be to solve this on your own. It is one of those things that are simple once you get it right, seeing the other answers you can see what are the other people trying and you could use that for your own solution. In my opinion if someone gives you a working code that you only copy/paste then you will be missing the learning opportunity.

Answer (score 1):

Some very simple ways to get started have been mentioned above, but this is the classic functional programming problem in JS. Problems like this are what make my day interesting.

```
Object.keys(THE_OBEJCT)
  .map(name =>
    THE_OBEJCT[name].map(device => ({
      id: name,
      Data: THE_OBEJCT[name].map(device => ({
        time: device.time,
        temperature: device.temperature
      }))
    }))
  )
  .map(d =>
    d.reduce((memo, d) => ({ id: d.id, data: memo.data.concat(d.Data) }), {
      data: []
    })
  )
```

Is very basic, but will create an array of objects that look like this...

[image: output]

Comment: This is great thanks. However i do not get the same output as you, what you have is correct..  This is the output i get: https://imgur.com/JjLT6Yi

Comment: you want Data as an array or an object?

Comment: I feel like the id needs to be outside the second map, so that there is only one ID and then data in the next array.

Comment: This is how it should look, imagine also there is multiple other device sets as in this example in the picture there is only one. https://imgur.com/u7Y1Vog

Comment: OK Ive updated to what i think you want. It could be cleaner, but there you go...

Comment: I would just like to add that this seems to be incredibly slow to process over around 2000 data points?? I believe this is because you have mapped over 4000 entries 4000 times!

Comment: Probably there are a bunch of loops in there, can prob clean it up, premature optimization is the root of all evil :P

Comment: try to incorporate the final map and reduce into the internal Data map, it should cut down of the iterations

Comment: if i have 4000 entries, then the map actually maps 4000 entries into each

Answer (score 0):

```
const newArr = []

Object.keys(myObject).map((key, index) => {
  newArr.push(
  {
    id: key,
    Data: [
      {
        x: myObject[key][0].time,
        y: myObject[key][0].temperature,
      }
    ],
  }
  )
});
```

Something like this perhaps.

Comment: Thanks, but i do not really understand the output of this at all? It seems to only output a small array = [1,2]